# How to get a label from a jenkins pipeline script using declarative groovy (Script console)

Tags: jenkins, groovy

[image]

We declare label in Pipeline script now I want to get that label using groovy script through Jenkins Script console.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label '**se-installer-01.cec.lab.emc.com**'
       
    }
    environment{
         version_parameter=''
         
     }
   stages { 
       stage ('Clean up the WS') {
                steps {
                    cleanWs()
                }
            }
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is unclear.  Below you say you want to `get` the label of the JOB - but jobs don't have labels, agents do.  Which of these are you asking:


1. Get a list of agents with a given label?  (there is a step for that: `nodesByLabel label: YOURLABELHERE, offline: true`)

2. Get the label(s) on the agent that the job runs on?  Env variable: **NODE_LABELS**

3. Get the NAME of the agent the build runs on? Env variable: **NODE_NAME**

By the way, you might want to change the title to correct the spelling of label.

Answer (score 0):

@Deepak, if I am understanding correctly you are trying to fetch node with specific label? May be you can add some details in question on what information you want to process by fetching label?

```
import jenkins.model.*
 jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.nodes.collect { node ->
        if (node.labelString.contains("<regex for label you want to find>")) 
        {
          //processing logic
        }
}
```

Comment: Let suppose we have a pipeline job and we declare label in Pipeline script (as shown in my question) and i want to fetch this information through groovy.

Comment: I want fetch Job with labels specified in Pipeline script

Comment: @DeepakRohilla: I'm not following either.  Please clarify your question (see my comment on your question for the 3 possible things I think you're asking)... but I suspect you're asking something quite different.

Comment: @SteventheEasilyAmused Thanks for clarification, i want to fetch label of pipeline job (without SCM)

Comment: @DeepakRohilla did you try the code that I have posted as an answer? Are you using shared library to fetch details? Could you please elaborate on " fetch label of pipeline job (without SCM)"?

Comment: The code Wanderer provided will not work in a sandboxed pipeline. Access to jenkins.model is restricted.  Wanderer's example WOULD work in the Script Console - which is indicative of the confusion we have in understanding your question, @DeepakRohilla
Please rework your question for clarity as it's not very productive for the community to try to tease out what you MAY have intended to ask.

Comment: I tried to clarify my problem in another question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68933350/10994299